# Are two-level schedulers only useful to manage swapping?

Tags: operating-systems, process-scheduling

[Two-level scheduling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-level_scheduling) is useful when a system is running more processes than fit in RAM: a lower-level scheduler switches between resident processes, and a higher-level scheduler swaps groups of processes in and out.

I find no other mention of two-level scheduling in Andrew Tanenbaum's *Operating Systems: Design and Implementation*, 1st ed. Exercise 2.22 asks why two-level scheduling might be used; I don't know whether it's there as a reading comprehension check or there are other reasons not prominently mentioned in the text.

Is two-level scheduling useful to manage other resource contentions, besides memory?

Comment: It might be good for caches and disk IO, but that is not "besides memory".

Comment: As @Raphael says, but in other words, it avoids/reduces thrashing.

Answer (score 8):

There are other forms of two-level scheduling than the type you describe.  For example, one level of scheduling could be per-user and the other could be per-process, aiming for giving a user with 20 processes the same amount of CPU time as a user with 1 process.  With a single-level scheduler, each process might get 1/21 of the CPU time.

Another form of two-level scheduling could be per-process and per-thread, aiming to give a process with 20 threads the same amount of CPU time as a process with 1 thread.